How long do Amortentia effects last?
I checked Potter Wiki and there's no details, nor do I remember anything in canon.
I think the implication (if not fact) is that Merope Gaunt probably used it on Tom Riddle Sr, and at some point stopped and the effect stopped?

IIRC, Dumbledore and Harry had a quick exchange about this in HBP, where Dumbledore opined that Merope stopped drugging Riddle Sr with it at some point. Hence, it does have a time-limited effect. (As with any drug, magical or otherwise.) Whether there is any lasting harm is unknown.
